# Set pygame surface DPI

Tags: python, pygame

I am rendering Mandelbrot fractal on a pygame surface from a numpy array.

When I generate a 10k px * 10k px image and save it using pylab in a 10 * 10 inch image with a 1000dpi I get a 10k pixels image which render pretty well when windows build in photo app display it with zoom ajustment.
In pygame, the image looks pretty ugly although it is displayed with the same size :

[image]

I'm using this code :

```
pygame.init()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 1000))
surf = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(gimage)

surf = pygame.transform.rotate(surf, 90)
surf = pygame.transform.scale(surf, (1000, 1000))
```

**How would one set pygame image size and ajust DPI ?**

Comment: read doc: [scale](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale) is "fast scale operation". There is also [smoothscale](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.smoothscale) which use different algorythm. Maybe it will give you better result.

Comment: you can also use `PIL/Pillow` to [resize()](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.3.x/reference/Image.html?highlight=resize#PIL.Image.Image.resize) with different methods of resampling. And you can display it with `PIL/Pillow` too.

Comment: So I should resize the 10k px to 1k px and then give it back to pygame ? 
I'm using pygame because I can explore Mandelbrot with keyboard, setting the boudaries and zoom property.

Comment: Smoothscale give much more better results. Thank you. Maybe you should add it as an answer.

Comment: try to resize image with `PIL/Pillow` or `CV2` and see if it gives better result. Yesterday there was question [how to use CV2 with PyGame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47614396/how-do-you-convert-3d-array-in-pygame-to-an-vaid-input-in-opencv-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[scale()](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale) is "fast scale operation" and doesn't use resampling.
There is also [smoothscale()](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.smoothscale) which uses different algorythm.
Maybe it will give you better result.

You can also use `PIL/Pillow` to [resize()](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.3.x/reference/Image.html?highlight=resize#PIL.Image.Image.resize) with different methods of resampling.

You can also try to use `CV2` to [resize()](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#void%20resize(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20Size%20dsize,%20double%20fx,%20double%20fy,%20int%20interpolation)).
Yesterday there was question [how to use CV2 with PyGame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47614396/how-do-you-convert-3d-array-in-pygame-to-an-vaid-input-in-opencv-python)